# dataframe ewm for groupby resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like below.

[image]

Is it possible to get exponential weighted mean like below? Below code throws error

```
df.groupby(['name']).resample('1s')['value'].ewm(span=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to ensure the dataframe index is a time series. Use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Then amend your code to:

```
df.groupby(['name']).resample('1s')['value'].ffill().ewm(span=1).mean()
```

`ffill()` is added before calling `ewm()` in order to convert the `DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby` object to DataFrame object which you can then use the `ewm()` function.

Test codes and output:

```
    data = {'time': ['0:00:02', '0:00:04', '0:00:06', '0:00:08'], 'name': ['n1', 'n2', 'n1', 'n2'], 'value': [10, 1000, 20, 1500]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
    df.groupby(['name']).resample('1s')['value'].ffill().ewm(span=1).mean()

name  time               
n1    1900-01-01 00:00:02      10.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:03      10.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:04      10.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:05      10.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:06      20.0
n2    1900-01-01 00:00:04    1000.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:05    1000.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:06    1000.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:07    1000.0
      1900-01-01 00:00:08    1500.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is not right. The `resample('1s')` is a misleading example because it's not binning the `n1` timestamps, but just selecting them one at a time. Also, the ffill step ends the grouping, hence the ewm is not applied per group. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by SeaBean is not right (reasons in my comment there).

To calculate an [exponentially weighted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) average (`ewm` then `mean` then `iloc[-1]`) on `DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby`, use `.apply(lambda s: s.ewm(...).mean().iloc[-1])`.

Here is the full example from SeaBean modified:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
   'time': ['0:00:02', '0:00:04', '0:00:06', '0:00:07', '0:00:09'],
   'name': ['n1', 'n2', 'n1', 'n2', 'n1'],
   'value': [10, 1000, 20, 1500, 30],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
display(
   df
   .groupby(['name'])
   .resample('8s')
   ['value']
   .apply(lambda s: s.ewm(alpha=.1).mean().iloc[-1])
)
```

Displayed output:

```
name  time               
n1    1900-01-01 00:00:00      15.263158
      1900-01-01 00:00:08      30.000000
n2    1900-01-01 00:00:00    1263.157895
Name: value, dtype: float64
```